# MVC3 Architecture/Validation Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap, fluentvalidation

I think this is a pretty simple task, but I can't for the life of me get it working.

Environment - MVC3, FluentValidation, StructureMap.

I have a ViewModel (RegisterViewModel) that has the following attributes { Email, IsBusiness, BusinessContact }.  Email is required always, BusinessContact is required if the IsBusiness checkbox is checked.

I was trying to perform the BusinessContact required check client side, but can't for the life of me figure out the right way to do this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to roll your own client side validation to enforce the constraint your looking for. Phil Haack has a great post on how to do this http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Otherwise you could just enforce the constraint server side and add an error to the ModalState and reload the view.